# asana tasks api does not work for GET /tasks GET /workspaces/workspace_id/tasks but for GET /projects/project_id

Tags: api, asana

My query were these:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks
But I have this error instead: "Must specify exactly one of project, tag, or workspace"

When I try out for the workspace with this:
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/workspace_id/tasks
I have this error: "assignee: Missing input"

However, I will get a list of tasks if i use the projects instead...

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

(I work at Asana)

You must always filter a task query with something, as we do not yet support pagination and all tasks in a workspaces will usually be a huge volume of data. Specifying a project implicitly scopes the query to a workspace, as every project exists in exactly one workspace. You can specify `assignee`, but then you must additionally filter by workspace.

So your choices for filtering tasks are either by `project` or by BOTH `assignee` and `workspace`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg, for your prompt response :)

Comment: FYI: When trying to get tasks via the API explorer, then filters on section or project doesn't work as the workspace is always given to the query.

So copy the generated URL and remove the workspace parameter from it and then it works.